# Can I assign a variable to an image made by a for loop in the loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, photoimage

I am creating a chinese checkers AI project, and I created the checkers using a for loop. What I want to ask is, is it possible to assign a variable to each checker I created with `create_image` with the for loop?
I use this code:

```
black = []
black = PhotoImage(file="black.gif")
black_sub = black.subsample(8, 8)
for i in range(4):
    black_id.append(i)

    canvas.create_image(425 + 24 * i,800 - 10 - 45 * i, anchor=S, 
    image=black_sub)

for i in range(4):

    black_id.append(i+4)

    canvas.create_image(425 - 24 * i,800 - 10 - 45 * i, anchor=S, 
    image=black_sub)
```

Can I possibly assign each list number to it's corresponding checker?

Comment: You should use lists for this.

Comment: Oh, right yeah. I included a list at the beginning.

Comment: Please provide some result what you expected.

Comment: I expect that i can move the checkers using their id. I have already made a list for the id's and i want to assign the id's using a for loop, then put them in the list.

Comment: where is where your checkers assigned to a variable?

Comment: I want to create it so that a variable is created in the for loop, then assign it to each checker. I am confused how to assign individual and different variables in a for loop. If i do i = canvas....., then it will just constantly change the variable, and not create one. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to define your question based of the given information, but you don't have to fetch ID-s, as it will be the index of your checker list, so you easily can get any of the checkers indexing with their id as follows:

```
black = PhotoImage(file="black.gif")
black_sub = black.subsample(8, 8)
checkers = []

for i in range(4):
    checkers.append( 
                    canvas.create_image(425 + 24 * i,800 - 10 - 45 * i, anchor=S, 
                    image=black_sub) 
                    )

for i in range(4):
    checkers.append( 
                    canvas.create_image(425 - 24 * i,800 - 10 - 45 * i, anchor=S, 
                    image=black_sub) 
                    )

checkers[5].move(10,10) # get some of the checker based on its ID
```